# If i am making a image sharing service website using the standard file upload form what images can i say it supports, other then jpg, png, gif

Tags: image, formats

If i am making a image sharing service website using the standard file upload form what images can i say it supports, other then jpg, png, gif. Is there a list that shows what browsers supports what? I know that jpg png and gif are most common but what are the others. I want to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, that's pretty much all you should be concerned with. Any other file formats (like svg) are not widely supported enough.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest converting other types of files to those 3

Examples:

1. jpeg (simple renaming)
2. bmp
3. tiff
4. pcx

Comment: im not talking about converting. Im saying with out converting, what images can they upload raw and the browser supports. Other then those i mentioned

Comment: Well then, just rename jpeg to jpg